# How to use params in GET request via EIA API v2 in Python?

Tags: python, get, viewparams

I am trying to read Crude Oil Production data from https://www.eia.gov/ using **GET request**. It is quite straightforward to read it in a single-line URL address. However, I can not use `params` within `requests.get(api_url, params=params)` command.

```
api_url = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/steo/data/'

params = {
    "api_key": xxxxxx,
    "frequency": "annual",
    "data": [
        "value"
    ],
    "facets": {
        "seriesId": [
            "COPR_OPEC",
            "PAPR_WORLD"
        ]
    },
    "start": "2000",
    "end": "2023",
    "sort": [
        {
            "column": "period",
            "direction": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 5000,
    "api-version": "2.0.2"
}

try:
    (r := requests.get(api_url, params=params)).raise_for_status()
    print(r.text[0:1000])
except Exception as e:
    print(f'Data acquisition failed due to {e}')
```

The error I am getting is:

> Error: 400 as data acquisition failed due to "Bad Request for URL":
> https‍://api.eia.gov/v2/steo/data/?api_key=xxxxxx&frequency=annual&data=value&facets=seriesId&start=2000&end=2023&sort=column&sort=direction&offset=0&length=5000

I can fix the issue by removing `"facets"`, `"api-version"`, and `"length"` from `"params"`; but I need to filter the JSON data later on.

I wonder if I am not using the correct structure for `"params"`. I couldn't find other Python sample code for using `"params"` on the EIA API v2 Dashboard.

[image: Figure 1: EIA API v2 "params" settings]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you had solved it yet but I had the same problem, and solved it in a rather dummy way. You are right in not getting the correct structure for "params". It seems like they structured the faucet in a rather layered way. There doesn't seem to be any instruction online to directly tackle that as well so I've decided to use the link generator they provided:

https://www.eia.gov/opendata/browser/petroleum/crd/crpdn

and then just code the square bracket as strings into the header:

For example:

```
url1 = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/petroleum/crd/crpdn/data/'
test = {
    "api_key": apikey,
    "frequency": "annual",
    "data[0]": "value",
    "facets[series][]": "MCRFPAKS1",
    "facets[series][]": "MCRFPAKS2",
    "start": "2000",
    "end": "2023",
    "sort[0][column]": "period",
    "sort[0][direction]": "desc",
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 5000,
    }
temp = requests.get(url1, params=test)
```

P.S., I think they changed the name from "seriesId" to "series", and I can't seem to find "COPR_OPEC" and "PAPR_WORLD" as well. But the codes above works. I've tested it.(make sure you get the API url right as well because I think they changed it from V1 to V2)

Answer (score 0):

Found this post trouble shooting a similar problem with EIA API v2. I think the easier route is to pass all `params` except `api_key` in as a `headers` argument to the `get` request. You can include `X-Params` as a `header` and dump all the API filters into the `header` as opposed to trying to compose the url via `params`.

Your `get` call would look like this. You need to call `json.dumps(header)` to convert the python dict to a str.

```
api_url = 'https://api.eia.gov/v2/steo/data'

params = {"api_key": xxxxxx}

header = {
    "frequency": "annual",
    "data": [
        "value"
    ],
    "facets": {
        "seriesId": [
            "COPR_OPEC",
            "PAPR_WORLD"
        ]
    },
    "start": "2000",
    "end": "2023",
    "sort": [
        {
            "column": "period",
            "direction": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "offset": 0,
    "length": 5000
}

r = request.get(api_url, params=params, headers={"X-Params": json.dumps(header)})
```